# How to produce xpath link with characters from [a-z]

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping data from the website and I need to iterate over pages, but instead of a counter they have an alphabetical index

```
    http://funny2.com/jokesb.htm'
    http://funny2.com/jokesc.htm')
    ...
```

But I can't figure out how to include the [a-z] iterator. I tried

```
    http://funny2.com/jokes^[a-z]+$.htm'
```

which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath doesn't support regular expressions. However as Scrapy built atop `lxml` it supports some EXSLT extensions, particularly `re` extension. You can use operations from EXSLT prepending them with corresponding namespace like this:

```
response.xpath('//a[re:test(@href, "jokes[a-z]+\.htm")]/@href')
```

Docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=selector#using-exslt-extensions

If you need just to extract the links, use `LinkExtractor` with regexp:

```
LinkExtractor(allow=r'/jokes[a-z]+\.htm').extract_links(response)
```

Comment: The solution that solved the problem for me:         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'http://funny2.com/jokes[a-z]+\.htm'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through every letter in the alphabet and format that letter into some url template:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

# 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
from char in ascii_lowercase:
    url = "http://funny2.com/jokes{}.htm".format(char)
```

In scrapy context, you need to find a way to increment character in the url. You can find it with regex, figure out the next character in alphabet and put it into the current url, something like:

```
import re    
from string import ascii_lowercase

def parse(self, response):
    current_char = re.findall('jokes(\w).htm', response.url)
    next_char = ascii_lowercase[current_char] + 1
    next_char = ascii_lowercase[next_char]
    next_url = re.sub('jokes(\w).htm', 'jokes{}.htm'.format(next_char), response.url)
    yield Request(next_url, self.parse2)
```

Comment: So my snippet is embedded in a scrapy function:   rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'http://funny2.com/jokes[INSERTION].htm'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    ). E.g. what i did for number was just add a '\d+' in the brackets and I was looking for something like that for lowercase.

Comment: @OliverEbrle see my edit for how to do it in the context of scrapy parse function.

Comment: @OliverEbrle `LinkExtractor(allow=r'funny2.com/jokes\w.htm')‌​` maybe? I'm not sure what's your question now. `\w` in regex stands for any word character.